# Not able to attach variables and functions with angularJS controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

when i am using $scope object to bind function and variable,and making changes accordingly in HTML the code is working fine ,but not with this object.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", myCtrl);
function myCtrl()
{
  console.log("registering app");
  this.valueOne="0";
  this.valueTwo="0";
  this.result="0";
  this.add=function () {
    console.log("in add");
      this.result=parseFloat(this.valueOne)+parseFloat(his.valueTwo);
      valueOne="";
      valueTwo="";
  }
  this.subtract=function () {
      this.result=parseFloat(this.valueOne)-parseFloat(his.valueTwo)
      valueOne="";
      valueTwo="";
  }

  this.multiply=function()  {
      this.result=parseFloat(this.valueOne)*parseFloat(his.valueTwo)
      valueOne="";
      valueTwo="";
  }
  this.divide=function()  {
      this.result=parseFloat(this.valueOne)/parseFloat(his.valueTwo)
      valueOne="";
      valueTwo="";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" >

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
 <p>Value 1 : <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.valueOne" placeholder="Value 1"></br>
   Value 2 : <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.valueTwo" placeholder="Value 2"></br>
<button ng-click="myCtrl.add()">Add</button>
<button ng-click="myCtrl.subtract()">subtract</button>
<button ng-click="myCtrl.divide()">divide</button>
<button ng-click="myCtrl.multiply()">multiply</button>
 </p>
 <h1>Calculation Result {{myCtrl.result}}</h1>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### And from where i am taking reference it is working fine there

```js
var app = angular.module("calculatorApp", []);
app.controller("CalculatorCtrl", CalculatorCtrl);

function CalculatorCtrl() {
    this.resultValue = 0;
    this.buttonClicked = function(button) {
        this.selectedOperation = button;
    }
    this.computeResult = function() {
        var number1 = parseFloat(this.input1);
        var number2 = parseFloat(this.input2);
        if (this.selectedOperation === '+') {
            this.resultValue = number1 + number2;
        }
        else if (this.selectedOperation === '-') {
            this.resultValue = number1 - number2;
        }
        else if (this.selectedOperation === '*') {
            this.resultValue = number1 * number2;
        }
        else if (this.selectedOperation === '/') {
            this.resultValue = number1 / number2;
        }



    }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<html ng-app="calculatorApp">

    <head>
        <title>Calculator App</title>
        <script src='angular.js'></script>
        <script src='app.js'></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Calculator App</h1>
        <div ng-controller="CalculatorCtrl as ctrl">
            <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.input1"></input>
            <span ng-bind="ctrl.selectedOperation"></span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.input2"></input>
            <button ng-click="ctrl.computeResult()">=</button>
            <span ng-bind="ctrl.resultValue"></span>
            <p>
                Choose operation:
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('+')">+</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('-')">-</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('*')">*</button>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.buttonClicked('/')">/</button>
            </p>
            
        </div>
        
    </body>

</html>
```

Not able to get what i am doing wrong .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you missed is a tiny detail:

In working code:

`ng-controller="CalculatorCtrl as ctrl"` it had this.

Where as, your code:

`ng-controller="myCtrl"` has this. **It means your HTML code didn't have a reference of your controller.**

You can just change it to `ng-controller="myCtrl as myCtrl"` and it should work fine!

Also, your code snippet was having occurances of `his` instead of `this` in controller methods. Fixed those. And following is your working snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", myCtrl);
function myCtrl()
{
  console.log("registering app");
  this.valueOne="0";
  this.valueTwo="0";
  this.result="0";
  this.add=function () {
    console.log("in add");
      this.result=parseFloat(this.valueOne)+parseFloat(this.valueTwo);
      valueOne="";
      valueTwo="";
  }
  this.subtract=function () {
      this.result=parseFloat(this.valueOne)-parseFloat(this.valueTwo)
      valueOne="";
      valueTwo="";
  }

  this.multiply=function()  {
      this.result=parseFloat(this.valueOne)*parseFloat(this.valueTwo)
      valueOne="";
      valueTwo="";
  }
  this.divide=function()  {
      this.result=parseFloat(this.valueOne)/parseFloat(this.valueTwo)
      valueOne="";
      valueTwo="";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
</script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" >

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as myCtrl">
 <p>Value 1 : <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.valueOne" placeholder="Value 1"></br>
   Value 2 : <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.valueTwo" placeholder="Value 2"></br>
<button ng-click="myCtrl.add()">Add</button>
<button ng-click="myCtrl.subtract()">subtract</button>
<button ng-click="myCtrl.divide()">divide</button>
<button ng-click="myCtrl.multiply()">multiply</button>
 </p>
 <h1>Calculation Result {{myCtrl.result}}</h1>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: o man really thanks,i ain't miss it ,i just thought it as an alias for big name calculator